# Typescript fill() similar to Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, typescript, typeorm

In Laravel, every database model has a `fill()` method that only assigns "mass assignable" fields into the class property. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment)

```
public class Rectangle {
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'length', 'width'];
}
```

So we can fill the properties like so:

```
$rect = new Rectangle();
$rect->fill([
    'name' => 'My Square',
    'length' => 25,
    'width' => 25,
    'foo' => 'bar', // this field will be ignored because it's not in $fillable
]);
```

---

Now I want to do something similar in typescript, I have a TypeORM model class with some fields:

```js
export class Requisition {
    title!: string;
    reference!: string;
}
```

In my service class, I have a function that receives data from an external endpoint with extra fields that I want to ignore.

How do I instantiate a `Requisition` class in a similar way to `->fill();`?

I would prefer to avoid manually writing a `fill()` method like this:

```js
fill(value: IRequisition) {
    this.title = value.title;
    this.reference = value.reference;
}
```

It should also needs to be generic so that I can add this functionality to all my model classes.

Comment: Are you trying to set default values to those properties?

Comment: nope, I want to fill the properties of the class with a set of data that contains extra properties that I don't want

Comment: Extra properties means, not part of your database table, but part of your model?

Comment: In this case, the data from the external endpoint comes with other fields instead of just title and requisition. I want to be able to automatically ignore these other fields - i.e. only assign the fields that I define.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Model that is similar to Laravel with abstract class

```js
abstract class Model {
  public fill(data: any, fillable?: string[]) {
    const self: any = this;
    Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
      if (!fillable || fillable.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
        self[key] = data[key];
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The `fill` function expect to get an object and the fillable fields, and if the field is fillable or the fillable array is not defined, the field will be mass-assigned.

The `Requisition` model will need to extend the `Model` class:

```
class Requisition extends Model {
  title!: string;
  reference!: string;
  protectedField: boolean = false;
}
```

And that's it!

You can fill the object like:

```
const fillable = ["title", "reference"];
const filled = new Requisition();
filled.fill({
    title: "title1",
    reference: "reference1",
    protectedField: true
  },
  fillable
);
```

Note that the `proctededField` is not been filled because it is not defined in the `fillable` array.